# Is the following multivariate function is bounded on any finite domain?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Wouldn't the function
$$
f(x,y) =  y^3 e^{(x^2 + y^2)} (x^2 + y^2)
$$
be bounded on any finite domain, since  $y^3$, $e^{(x^2 + y^2)}$, and $(x^2 + y^2)$ are bounded on any finite domain?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, suppose for a bounded domain, suppose that functions $f_i$ are bounded, that is $$ |f_i| \leq M_i$$

then we have $$ \prod_i |f_i| \leq \ \prod_i M_i.$$

That is product of bounded function is bounded.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I imagine he meant by a finite domain a bounded domain. Otherwise this that's trivial

Comment: I don't know what this answer shows.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I am just claiming that products of bounded functions are bounded. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I understood, now.